# Deleting a category from WordPress admin does it remove it completely from the database?

Tags: categories, database

When you delete a category in the admin of WordPress does it completely remove it from the database?

I had a few categories with the same naming conventions (different slugs) but now deleting any categories having the same names and creating a complete new category but I wanted to make sure the old categories is completely erased out of the database, does this happen automcatically?

Comment: Perhaps a WordPress 4.2 [Taxonomy Term Splitting affected](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/02/16/taxonomy-term-splitting-in-4-2-a-developer-guide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the categories are stored in `wp_terms` table which contains the term_id, name and slug. Deleting the category in admin panel removes the three values along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, When you create categories,WordPress inserts detail in two tables **WP_terms** and **WP_term_taxonomy** .So when you delete category all entries does deleted.

```
if you assign any post of that category.all post are automatically assign **uncategory**
```